# ASP.NET_SessionId cookie not reflecting on the IIS welcome page

Tags: asp.net, iis, cookies

In IIS manager, i've enabled the session state and set it to use cookies. Whilst I have no problems setting custom HTTP response headers/custom cookies, the built-in ASP.NET_SessionId cookie isn't reflecting on the browser. What do I do to make the cookie be issued because I can't see it in the response headers on the browser developer tools.

I've followed the basic steps shown on multiple different websites to setup the cookie. I've ensured its in the correct mode as well as checking the web.config file to ensure the code is correct. However, whenever I launch the browser and check the developer tools, I see the custom response header and cookie I set but not the built-in ASP.NET_SessionId cookie.

Comment: but does session work, which is not browser based? In other words, if session is working server side (code behind), then obviosity the session id is not being seen by your use of the browser dev tools - it likely burred in viewstate. So, if session is working, then its working, right? Remember, viewstate = browser side based, and session = server side based and managed. General session based values thus don't appear in browser, nor are they part of the browser cache or viewstate.

Comment: Refer to this link for session state: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-2-configure-asp-net-settings#21-session-state-settings.

Comment: i've already followed the instructions on that website and the result was the same. Unable to reflect the default cookie on the browser.

Comment: Session Cookie is a non-persistent cookie and is not stored on the hard drive (kept in memory only), so you can't view it. Non-Persistent cookies are stored in RAM on the client and are destroyed when the browser is closed.

Comment: how do i then verify that the cookie flags and other configurations that i have set for the cookie are correct. I'm trying to get it to reflect on the browser so that i can verify the configurations, is there any other way to verify?